# Folder Redirection only applies if I run gpupdate /force - File Server Migration

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012, group-policy, windows-server-2016, folder-redirection

We have just migrated the home shares of approximately 2300 users to a new file server. For some reason folder redirection is not updating the paths for any existing user profiles (we don't use roaming profiles). However if I run `gpupdate /force` while that individual user is logged on to a PC on which they already had a profile, folder redirection applies correctly. This is becoming a big problem as our users move around a lot.

In active directory under each user's Profile tab we have set:
`Connect: Z: To: \\FileServer\Share\Username`
This works fine.

We haven't changed our folder structures from the XP layout yet (I.e. Pictures, Music etc are still inside Documents) despite removing XP a long time ago, so our redirection policy is as follows:

> User Configuration linked to OU containing our user accounts
>
> **Documents**
>
> - Basic - Redirect everyone's folder to the same location
> - Redirect to the user's home directory
> - Grant the user exclusive rights to Documents
> - Leave the folder in the new location when policy is removed
>
> **Pictures** Follow the Documents folder
>
> **Music** Follow the Documents folder
>
> **Videos** Follow the Documents folder
>
> **Desktop**
>
> - Basic - Redirect everyone's folder to the same location
> - Redirect to the following location: `%HOMESHARE%\Desktop`
> - Leave the folder in the new location when policy is removed
>
> **Favorites**
>
> - Basic - Redirect everyone's folder to the same location
> - Redirect to the following location: `%HOMESHARE%\Favorites`
> - Leave the folder in the new location when policy is
>     removed

---

> Computer Configuration linked to OU containing our computers
>
> Policies\Administrative Templates\System\Group Policy:
>
> - Configure folder redirection policy processing
>     `Process even if the Group Policy objects have not changed: Enabled`

**Share Permissions:**

> - Staff: Full Control
> - Domain Admins: Full Control

**Shared Folder's NTFS Permissions:**

> Inheritance: Disabled
>
> - CREATOR OWNER: Full control (Subfolders and files only)
> - SYSTEM: Full control (This folder, subfolders and files)
> - Administrators: Full control (This folder, subfolders and files)
> - Domain Users: Travers folder/execute file, List folder/read data, Read attributes, Create folders/append data (This folder only)

Here is the result of `gpresult /user username /v`. I have removed all of the excess policies to make it shorter. The reason I was adding this is to show that the folder redirection policy is not being filtered out etc and that the folder redirection section of the report says `N/A`. If you need to know anything about any other polices I have enabled please ask.

```
RSOP data for DomainRemoved\UserRemoved on F701 : Logging Mode
-------------------------------------------------------------

OS Configuration:            Member Workstation
OS Version:                  10.0.14393
Site Name:                   Removed
Roaming Profile:             N/A
Local Profile:               C:\Users\UserRemoved
Connected over a slow link?: No


COMPUTER SETTINGS
------------------
    CN=F701,OU=F7,OU=IT Computers,OU=First Floor,OU=Main Block,OU=Computers,OU=Company,DC=domain,DC=removed
    Last time Group Policy was applied: 08/07/2017 at 13:11:32
    Group Policy was applied from:      DCName.domain.removed
    Group Policy slow link threshold:   500 kbps
    Domain Name:                        DomainRemoved
    Domain Type:                        Windows 2008 or later

    Applied Group Policy Objects
    -----------------------------
        Internet Connection & Firewall Policy
        BootCamp Fixes
        Interactive Logon Policy
        Fix Daylight Savings
        Win10 Computer Policy
        Computer Software Restrictions (AppLocker)
        Apogee Printers
        Temp Fix for Folder Redirection
        Default Domain Policy

    The following GPOs were not applied because they were filtered out
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
        Whole School Software Win7
            Filtering:  Denied (WMI Filter)
            WMI Filter: Apply to Windows 7 Only

        Win 7 Computer Policy Extension
            Filtering:  Denied (WMI Filter)
            WMI Filter: Apply to Windows 7 Only

        Local Group Policy
            Filtering:  Not Applied (Empty)

        Computer Policy
            Filtering:  Denied (WMI Filter)
            WMI Filter: Apply to Windows 7 Only

    The computer is a part of the following security groups
    -------------------------------------------------------
        BUILTIN\Administrators
        Everyone
        BUILTIN\Users
        NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK
        NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
        This Organization
        F701$
        Domain Computers
        Authentication authority asserted identity
        CERTSVC_DCOM_ACCESS
        System Mandatory Level

    Resultant Set Of Policies for Computer
    ---------------------------------------

         Administrative Templates
        ------------------------

    REMOVED EXCESS POLICIES TO SHORTEN

            GPO: Win10 Computer Policy
                Folder Id: Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\NetCache\NoMakeAvailableOffline
                Value:       1, 0, 0, 0
                State:       Enabled

            GPO: Temp Fix for Folder Redirection
                Folder Id: Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Group Policy\{25537BA6-77A8-11D2-9B6C-0000F8080861}\NoSlowLink
                Value:       1, 0, 0, 0
                State:       Enabled

            GPO: Default Domain Policy
                Folder Id: Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\SyncForegroundPolicy
                Value:       1, 0, 0, 0
                State:       Enabled

            GPO: Temp Fix for Folder Redirection
                Folder Id: Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\Group Policy\{25537BA6-77A8-11D2-9B6C-0000F8080861}\NoGPOListChanges
                Value:       0, 0, 0, 0
                State:       Enabled

USER SETTINGS
--------------
    CN=Users Name,OU=Teaching Staff,OU=Staff,OU=Company,DC=domain,DC=removed
    Last time Group Policy was applied: 08/07/2017 at 12:22:59
    Group Policy was applied from:      N/A
    Group Policy slow link threshold:   500 kbps
    Domain Name:                        DomainRemoved
    Domain Type:                        Windows 2008 or later

    Applied Group Policy Objects
    -----------------------------
        Internet Connection & Firewall Policy
        Folder Redirection Policy
        Smoothwall Staff Proxy Settings
        Screensaver
        Win10 Base User Policy
        Win10 Staff Policy
        Apogee Printers
        Default Domain Policy

    The following GPOs were not applied because they were filtered out
    -------------------------------------------------------------------
        Staff
            Filtering:  Denied (WMI Filter)
            WMI Filter: Apply to Windows 7 Only

        Win 7 Staff Policy
            Filtering:  Denied (WMI Filter)
            WMI Filter: Apply to Windows 7 Only

        Local Group Policy
            Filtering:  Not Applied (Empty)

    The user is a part of the following security groups
    ---------------------------------------------------
        Domain Users
        Everyone
        BUILTIN\Users
        NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE
        CONSOLE LOGON
        NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users
        This Organization
        LOCAL
        WiFi Access
        PaperCut Welsh Bacc
        PaperCut Welsh Bacc Adv
        Staff
        Smoothwall Staff
        Admin Network Users
        PaperCut Computing
        HoD
        CERTSVC_DCOM_ACCESS
        Medium Mandatory Level

    The user has the following security privileges
    ----------------------------------------------

        Bypass traverse checking
        Increase a process working set
        Shut down the system
        Remove computer from docking station

    Resultant Set Of Policies for User
    -----------------------------------

        Administrative Templates
        ------------------------

    REMOVED EXCESS POLICIES TO SHORTEN

        Folder Redirection
        ------------------
            N/A
```

We are in the process of migrating to virtual servers and haven't removed our old DC's yet. For that reason we currently have 5 DC's with mixed OS:

2 x Server 2016
1 x Server 2012
2 x Server 2008 R2

Our forest and domain functional levels are both currently 2008 R2.

Our client PC's are Windows 10 1607 64 Bit.

I've tried to include as much info as possible but if you need anything else please ask.

EDIT:

Loopback processing is NOT enabled.
RSoP.msc is not showing any errors.
gpresult HTML output shows: Folder Redirection Success 703 Millisecond(s)